# Turn Data from Streamlit into CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, streamlit

I have the script below I typed in Pycharm for my Streamlit Data app:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import streamlit as st

st.set_page_config(page_title='Matching Application Number', 
                   layout='wide')
df = pd.read_csv('Analysis_1.csv')

st.sidebar.header("Filter Data:")
MeetingFileType = st.sidebar.multiselect(
    "Select File Type:",
    options=df['MEETING_FILE_TYPE'].unique(),
    default=df['MEETING_FILE_TYPE'].unique()
)

df_selection = df.query(
    'MEETING_FILE_TYPE == @MeetingFileType'
)

st.dataframe(df_selection)
```

The output of this on streamlit is:

```
Application_ID    MEETING_FILE_TYPE
BBC#:1010         1     
NBA#:1111         2
BRC#:1212         1
SAC#:1412         4
QRD#:1912         2
BBA#:1092         4
```

How can I return matching Application_ID results just for 1&2 like below:

```
Filter Data:               Application_ID     MEETING_FILE_TYPE
select type:               BBC#:1010          1 
1 2                        NBA#:1111          2
                           BRC#:1212          1
                           QRD#:1912          2
```

Then, how can I download the data results above from Streamlit into a csv file?, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look on the code comments.

##### Code

```
...

st.dataframe(df_selection)

# Show download button for the selected frame.
# Ref.: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.download_button
csv = df_selection.to_csv(index=False).encode('utf-8')
st.download_button(
     label="Download data as CSV",
     data=csv,
     file_name='selected_df.csv',
     mime='text/csv',
 )
```

##### Streamlit output

[image]

##### Downloaded csv file selected_df.csv when viewed from excel.

[image]

##### Full code

I am using your code.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import streamlit as st

data = {
    "Application_ID": ['BBC#:1010', 'NBA#:1111', 'BRC#:1212',
                       'SAC#:1412', 'QRD#:1912', 'BBA#:1092'],
    "MEETING_FILE_TYPE": [1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4]
}


st.set_page_config(page_title='Matching Application Number', 
                   layout='wide')
# df = pd.read_csv('Analysis_1.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

st.sidebar.header("Filter Data:")
MeetingFileType = st.sidebar.multiselect(
    "Select File Type:",
    options=df['MEETING_FILE_TYPE'].unique(),
    default=df['MEETING_FILE_TYPE'].unique()
)

df_selection = df.query(
    'MEETING_FILE_TYPE == @MeetingFileType'
)

st.dataframe(df_selection)

# Show download button for the selected frame.
# Ref.: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.download_button
csv = df_selection.to_csv(index=False).encode('utf-8')
st.download_button(
     label="Download data as CSV",
     data=csv,
     file_name='selected_df.csv',
     mime='text/csv',
 )
```

Comment: Thank you.. What scripts did you use to filter the data, so that it will only return rows that have only 1&2 File Type.

Comment: I use your code. Answer is updated, full code is added.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! The only problem is it is giving me all the Application_ID for MEETING_FILE_TYPE 1 + all the Application_ID for MEETING_FILE_TYPE  2. I just want it to return only the Application_ID that MEETING_FILE_TYPE 1 & 2 have in common. I want to define my "MeetingFileType" as a joint function that will only return matching join Application_IDs that are MEETING_FILE_TYPE 1 and MEETING_FILE_TYPE  2 at the same time. Thank you!!

Comment: Like for instance, to make it clear, I am going to use SQL language to explain my question: I am looking to do an INNER JOIN that will return all the records Application_ID that have matching values in both MEETING_FILE_TYPE 1 & 2 rows from my Analysis_1.csv file, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use csv module to export your output as csv file

```
import csv

with open('filename.csv') as csvfile:
   writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
   writer.writerow(df_selection)
```